# Conexion internet IOS Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Es posible deshabilitar la conexión a internet en el simulador de IOS de xcode 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una herramienta de xcode que simula entornos de conectividad buenos y malos. Quizás puedas simular una conexión mala malisima y/o practicamente nula o nula y asi no tener internet en el simulador. A ver si te sirve. (http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción que te podría servir sería simular un red lenta, este paquete de github te podría ayudar.
(https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)

Comment: Esta opción ya la probé pero el simulador me dejó de funcionar. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Pues si resuelves que el simulador no te funciona bien, está es la buena respuesta. Es muy buena herramienta. Mire donde mire todos la recomiendan.

Answer (score 1):

al final lo "solucioné" de la siguiente manera:

```
func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }


    if !isConnectedToNetwork() {//Por defecto da 1, al añadir !, simulo que no hay internet
        leo de bbdd
    }
    else {
        leo de xml
    }
```

Comment: Te felicito! Ahora tenemos multiples respuestas a un mismo problema y servirá a muchos con la misma necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque sea muy banal, desconecta la Wifi cuando lo necesites y listo. Sino, puedes utilizar la herramienta que comenta el compañero.